# MySQL - Trigger for updating same table after insert comparing the text

Tags: mysql, triggers

## Need Help with MYSQL Trigger with IF TEXT contains condition

Here's what I'm trying to do on MYSQL:

When there's an update on the table (i,e) when the "status" is changed from 'open' to "closed", i want to update date_closed to current date.

Trigger with if condition {**could not get it to work**}

```
create TRIGGER update_close_date BEFORE UPDATE ON issues 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    if LOCATE('closed', NEW.status) !=0 THEN
        SET new.date_closed = CURRENT_DATE;
    end if;
    END;
```

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `issues` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `project_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `assessment_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `issue_title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `severity` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `found_on` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `target_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_support_contact` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manager` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `date_closed` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `reminder_count` int(5) DEFAULT 0,
  `escalation_count` int(5) DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Update**

Thanks for the support, figured out whats wrong, had to add Delimiter word :)

```
DELIMITER //
create TRIGGER update_close_date BEFORE UPDATE ON issues 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    if LOCATE('closed', NEW.status) !=0 THEN
        SET new.date_closed = CURRENT_DATE;
    end if;
    END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: *```.. if LOCATE('closed', NEW.status) ..```* - does the `status` value may contain the substring `closed` but be not equal to it?

Comment: Why don't you add the condition in the update clause ?

Comment: The trigger text is correct. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6924d13838cb6b853f60cababcf8b62

Comment: @ErgestBasha *You can't modify same table with trigger* OP modifies the column value of the updated row in BEFORE trigger - this is correct.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Maybe in your case your method is more reasonable. But your preference does not effect the possibility to alter the value in a trigger in general.